# Retrofit : RestAdapter.Builder() vs Retrofit.Builder()

Tags: android, retrofit

Am confused in  usage of  `RestAdapter.Builder()`  and `Retrofit.Builder()` ? When  `RestAdapter.Builder()`  is used and when  `Retrofit.Builder()` ?

Comment: @FiN - thanks. may be you can update it as Answer so I can accept and upvote it :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RestAdapter` is replaced with `Retrofit` in the version `Retrofit 2`